# Is charging a capacitor to a new DC voltage fundamentally lossy?

Tags: capacitor, charge, physics, loss

There has recently been a question about switching losses and Landauer's principle entered the discussion. I included it [in my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/614025/237061) because I believe, a capacitor fundamentally cannot be charged without loss. If it could, it would violate Landauer's principle.

**Definition:**

In the context of this question (and of the linked question), I define charging as attaining a new stable DC voltage.

**Background:**

It is well known, that if you connect a capacitor to some differential voltage source, it will charge to this new voltage with an RC time constant, and the losses incurred in R are 50% of the energy change of the capacitor charge.

Some comments under my answer suggested that switch mode power supplies demonstrate, that capacitors can be charged with greater than 50% efficiency, but I think that this doesn't qualify the above definition of charging, and would thus be useless for deterministic logic.

I simulated such a circuit in spice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn1dNi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All components are lossless. However, when checking the resulting energy in the capacitor after a short button "tap", it is always less than 50% of the energy expended by V1.

**So the question is:**

Is it at all possible to change the stable DC voltage across a capacitor without dissipating at least 50% of the energy ?

**Amendment:**

I see my mistake of not including the second switch that discharges the inductor into the capacitor. This gives basically 100% efficiency with ideal components.

Isn't this then in conflict with Landauer's principle? Namely if the charge state encodes a stable bit, then irreversible switching between the bits necessitates energy dissipation, according to thermodynamics.

Comment: Isn't that wasting the energy stored in the magnetic field? Put a diode to allow the collapsing magnetic field to charge the capacitor.

Comment: What if you add a diode, whose anode is connected to ground, and whose cathode is connected between the switch and inductor? Then you have a buck converter.

Comment: A SMPS allows theoretically zero loss for an ideal capacitor and SMPS.

Comment: You are all right. I see now that much higher efficiency than 50% can be realized . I just wonder, how doesn't this violate thermodynamics, e.g. Landauer's limit.

Comment: It obviously doesn’t violate any natural law: it wouldn’t work then. Usually the problem is in how some model of reality is used to reason about said reality: it’s easy to misapply models and “predict” results that are non-physical and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not clear how Landauer's limit, which relates to *information*, applies here?

Comment: @pjc50 if the charge state encodes a stable bit, then irreversible switching between the bits necessitates energy loss, according to thermodynamics. Added to the main question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, a capacitor can be charged to a particular voltage without losing any energy in the electric circuit itself. To do this, use the following circuit:

[image: A charging circuit using an inductor and a single-pole triple-throw switch.]

The procedure is:

1. Measure the voltage of the capacitor.
2. Calculate the amount of time which will be needed for the following two steps.
3. Throw the switch to the top (positive) position for some amount of time in order to charge the inductor.
4. Throw the switch to the bottom (negative) position for some amount of time in order to discharge the inductor.
5. Throw the switch to the center (unconnected) position, when the current through the inductor is 0 and the voltage across the capacitor is the desired voltage.
6. Dispose of the number calculated in step 2 by reversing the calculation.
7. Erase the number measured in step 1.

There's no violation of Landauer's principle because performing step 7 requires the expenditure of energy.

Comment: Yep. This is a version of Maxwell's Demon, with the same limitation (you must erase information at some point in the cycle).

Comment: thanks also @JohnDoty the analogy to Maxwells demon helped me a lot to better understand this answer. Btw what a story that thought experiment! So much scientific progress for generations out of a simple mind game

Answer (score 9):

> Is it at all possible to change the stable DC voltage across a capacitor without dissipating at least 50% of the energy ?

Of course! Just use a current source instead of a voltage source. And the current source should be an efficient switched one. Typically, that’s how switching regulators are configured: the inductor acts as a current source that charges a capacitor. The inefficiencies are related to ESRs, switching losses, gate drive losses, capacitor dissipation etc. They can be kept way under 50% of the capacitor’s energy across a whole charge cycle from 0V to final voltage.

Comment: I totally agree as per my amendment at the end of the question. There was no answer when I made that amendment, so I am sorry if it came at the same time as your answer..

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember that circuit theory is a simplified model of reality. Those simplifications can and do lead to contradictions, both internal contradictions and contradictions with other aspects of physics.

If you have an ideal switch, an ideal capacitor, an ideal inductor and an ideal diode you can charge the capacitor with 100% efficiency.

Ideal components don't physically exist, so with real components you will never reach 100% efficiency, you can certainly do a heck of a lot better than 50% though.